# Rails - How to validate the state of associated models as a state of the parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, activerecord, transactions

I'm building an API using rails for the backend of an ember webapp.  We have a model named 'Palette' which has many colors associated with it.  Due to the way the ember app is built, we are deleting the colors and replacing them with new objects whenever the palette is updated.  The challenge is that if the new state of the colors is no longer valid, we have already deleted the old colors and cannot return to the original state.  The only solution we have so far is to create a transaction in our update method of the palette controller which will throw an exception if any of the new color creations fails or the palette fails.  While this solution works, it feels a bit clunky.  Is there a more elegant solution available?

```
class PalettesController < BaseController

  def update
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      begin
        palette = Palette.find params[:id]
        palette.destroy_colors
        params[:palette][:colors].each do |color|
        Color.create! palette: palette, 
                    name: color[:name], 
                    cmyk: color[:cmyk],
                    color_type: color[:color_type]
        end
        return render json: palette.errors, 
          status: :unprocessable_entity unless palette.save!
      rescue
        return render json: { error: 'Unable to process the request' }.to_json, 
          status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
      render json: palette, status: 200
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve it like this, add the following code to your palette model:

```
validate :all_colors_valid  

def all_colors_valid
  colors.each do |color|
    errors.add('Color', 'invalid') unless color.valid?
  end
end
```

whenever you save an ActiveRecord object it goes through a whole bunch of steps described in the link below. One of them is validate which can be either rails standard validations or you can write your own custom validations.

If the object being saved has any errors after the validate phase the save action is aborted and no changes are made in the database.

The two parameters sent to `errors.add` is name of the column with the error and what the problem is. You could make this better by maybe saying which of the colours are bad or something like that.

Note that the new colours are not created after this validation is ok. It only guarantees that they could all be saved without error.

If you want them to be save by the palette model automatically i suggest you do that in an `after_save` action.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  My understanding is that if the validation method fails, then only the palette object reverts back to its original state.  The deleted colors would still be deleted, which wouldn't work because we want to revert to their old state.

Comment: How about saving the old colors in a temp palette and `if palette.save` delete them? `else` move them back?

Comment: That would probably work too.  What advantages do you suggest it offers over the transaction solution I posted?

Comment: Looking over your code again I would probably merge our 2 solutions. I think doing it in a transaction is the right way to go. But I would move the loop and the logic into a model method. Something like `Palette.update_colors(params[:palette][:colors])`